# Review my partitioning strategy and partition information of Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

I've installed Ubuntu Server 10.04, for serving as a samba server and development web server in my home network, on the following box:

- Pentium III 733MHz @133MHz
- 768 MB RAM
- HD 1: 20.5 GB
- HD 2: 41 GB

What I did, as far as partitioning is concerned, is as followed:

HD 1:

- Primary partition [/] 19 GB
- Logical partition [swap] 1.5 GB

HD 2:

- Logical partition [/home] 41 GB

Is this a reasonable configuration? Coming from a predominantly Windows (and a little bit of Mac OS X) environment, I believe a primary partition is needed for booting the system. But I think I read that I could do away with a primary partition altogether for a linux environment, and make it a logical partition as well, because Linux can boot from a logical partition. I believe this was suggested to make creating a multi boot system easier. While I don't have a need for a multi boot system though, is using only logical partitions still advisable nonetheless?

Furthermore, when printing out the partitioning info, I expected partitions to be named consecutively as:

```
/dev/sda1 Linux
/dev/sda2 Linux swap / Solaris

/dev/sdb1 Linux
```

But got:

```
/dev/sda1 Linux
/dev/sda2 Extended
/dev/sda5 Linux swap / Solaris

/dev/sdb1 Extended
/dev/sdb5 Linux
```

Now, if memory serves me correct, an extended partition is indeed needed for a logical partition. This is correct, right? However, what I don't understand is why the logical partitions are numbered sda5 and sdb5 in stead of sda3 and sdb2 respectively. Is this a sign that there are still undiscovered / hidden partitions on both drives? Or is this a conventional naming strategy I was unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very reasonable configuration for two drives and for a home server/dev machine.  If you were only on one drive, I'd avoid `/home` altogether, personally; if you don't make a separate `/home` partition, files located on that path would simply share space with everything else on the `/` partition.  In Unix, you mount partitions or devices (such as CD/DVD-ROM drives) onto paths; when mounted, all files under that path are then accessed from the partition or device mounted there.

Think of `/` as your `C:` drive--the system and all your software will go there, while `/home` is where you will keep all of your user data, your files, your source code, etc.

As for `sda5` et al, you're right that it's a naming strategy: `sda1` through `sda4` are primary partitions, and `sda5` on are logical partitions.  Making logical partitions is simply a default behavior in the interest of preserving the limited number of primary partitions available.  It would work equally as well if it was `sda2` or `sda5`.

I've actually never booted from a logical partition (your boot partition is `/` here; the boot files actually live under `/boot`) and therefore don't know how wise or not it is, but I don't think you need to think about it here either since you specify you are not expecting to multi-boot this machine.  Logical partitions are a mechanism for getting around the 4 primary partition limit and many boot managers only have the capability to boot from a primary partition.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the reassurance. You said: `If you were only on one drive, I'd avoid /home altogether, personally.` I wasn't even aware of this possibility. Where would one typically keep all the user data, in such a setup, then? Lastly, if possible, would you be able to say something meaningful about using a primary vs. logical partition as a system partition, as well? Thanks.

Comment: I edited to add some more.

Comment: OK, sounds reasonable enough indeed. Thanks again zigg.